# remove wp- prefix from wordpress files and folders

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to remove the wp prefix from all the wordpress folders and core files? I know that is it possible to change the admin folder name, but what about all other folders and files? I ask this because I want to remove wp prefix by modifying the core files. Another question about this CMS is about the dashboard. Is it possible to remove all the unwanted features, I want a light version of the CMS that is responsable only to create the contents using the built-in editor and to login the users. No theming and advanced settings or plugin needed, for this I can use pure php.

Answer (score 1):

Editing the core files is extremely bad idea and will definitely lead to a number of problems. About your second question - yes, it is possible to remove all the unnecessary nodes from the dashboard nav - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_node

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will look at codex, your link is very helping me. I know, About the wp- prefix, I'm looking at the code and it's very difficult to understand how many files are using common `wp-` named .php scripts. But with your answer I can think that it's possible. ?